# Read large data using Input Stream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

I have InputStream object which I need to read the data which is very large >50MB. I am trying to use below code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
InputStream fis = response.getResponseStream();
byte[] chunk = new byte[10240000];
int i = 0;
while ((i = fis.read(chunk)) != -1) {
          fos.write(chunk, 0, i);

}
```

But this is taking a lot of time. On debugging found that this is reading only 10kb at time although I am using 10240000 bytes.

Am I doing something wrong here? Please let me know how to improve the performance and to read maybe 1MB of data at a time.

Comment: What is `response` and where does it come from? Also what concrete implementation type is `fis`? (use `getClass()` to find out).

Comment: For that much data, I'd use a BufferedInputStream (or BufferedInputReader if this is text).

Comment: Is the source of the _response stream_ on a different computer? In other words, are you reading this data over a socket?

Comment: @NomadMaker a `BufferedInputStream` does not improve anything. The best thing it does, is go out of the way when the specified array is larger than its own buffer.

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. Just use [`Files.copy(response.getResponseStream(), Paths.get("test.txt"));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)). But it will take as long as it takes. I.e., when the source is a slow network connection, it will be as fast as that slow network connection can be.